# wrong format of exported file

Tags: php

I have following codes for exporting from my php file

```
 header("Content-type: application/msexcel");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exceldata.xls");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");"
```

This code produces following error

> The file you are trying to open is in a different format than
>   specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted
>   and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to
>   open the file now?

Please suggest some solution?Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, what format are you outputting? If you're trying to mask HTML code as an XLS file, the warning is kinda justified

Comment: And what format your file actually has? I guess error is shown by excel, right? Maybe you are working with csv?

Comment: Have you tried `header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");` or `header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");`

Comment: application/vnd.ms-excel is the correct mime type, though it won't fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error if the file you're generating is not an Excel BIFF-format file (e.g. if it's a CSV or HTML Markup). Eithe rcreate the correct format file using one of the many libraries available for PHP to generate real Excel files, or use the correct mimetype and extension for the file that you're actually creating.